# Slick Carousel: Stop navigation when last item is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I have a simple carousel of items which have the same width.

[image]

I want to stop the carousel navigation (with the arrows and by dragging the carousel), when the *last* item in the carousel is visible in the *right* side of the carousel.

*Currently*, you can keep pressing the `next` arrow button to navigate until the last item is in the left side of the carousel, like this:

[image]

The *desired* outcome, as explained above, looks like this:

[image]

It seemed like setting `edgeFriction` to 0 would solve my problem, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe I don't understand this well enough and the [documentation](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) isn't clear enough?

[HERE'S A FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/aerra/xf5mwtgp/23/)

HTML

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="text">
      <strong>FIRST</strong> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit necessitatibus, voluptate doloribus temporibus, fuga inventore iure repellat unde amet error accusantium cum et assumenda quae rerum laudantium voluptas facere obcaecati?
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593444461581-b5ae72d3b637?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.carousel').slick({
    variableWidth: true,
    loop: false,
    infinite: false,
    dots: false,
    arrows: true,
    appendArrows: $('.append')
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of your parameter `variableWidth` is set to true. Since all items are the same width, you don't need it.

Using these settings should work.

```
$('.carousel').slick({
  loop: false,
  infinite: false,
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  appendArrows: $('.append'),
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xrj8tcz/)

Keep in mind that you can change `slidesToShow` at specific breakpoint for responsiveness.